# Best way to use the Firefox search box input to construct a url and navigate to it

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox

I'd like to use the Firefox search field at the top right to automatically navigate to a particular URL based on the value of the search string.

**Example:** If I type "Kangaroo" and hit enter I'd like to navigate to "http://example.org/?q=Kangaroo".

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be easy : Define the URL as a bookmark, then go to its properties and add a keyword. You can then use this keyword as a shortcut to that URL.

[image]

For more information, see for example : [Keyword Bookmarks Catalogs Handy Firefox Keyword Strings](http://lifehacker.com/5504387/keyword-bookmarks-catalogs-handy-firefox-keyword-strings).

Comment: Thanks - this is the best solution I've found so far. I've set the bookmark to `http://example.org/?q=%s`, and it looks like `%s` is replaced by the string I type (for example I can type `e Kangaroo`). If I decide I want to set up a search box at the top right instead of typing this into the address bar, is it possible to have two search boxes (one for Google and another one next to it) in FF5?

Comment: Multiple search boxes are mentioned as a [FF feature request](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Feature_Brainstorming:Search_and_Find#Multiple_search_boxes). There is a possible solution [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=233888), but it's quite old.

Comment: @Andrew You can install Google Toolbar and get one Google search box from it. You'll have to `Customize...` the toolbars to move the box from the Google Toolbar to your address toolbar. Then you can hide the Google toolbar. Also, if you set Google as your default search engine and type more than one words (or any string that contains a space) the browser will launch a search as opposed to treating the words as URL.

Answer (score 5):

Did you know Firefox search bar supports keyword for each search engine ? For example : type **g superuser** in address bar you will get http://www.google.com/search?q=superuser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

O'Reilly has detailed tutorial on creating a Firefox search plugin from scratch here
http://oreilly.com/pub/h/3033.